# Rotate React Native Image around a pivot point

Tags: react-native

I would like to rotate a React Native Image based on an x/y point on the image, rather than the default centre.

Say I have a needle image and I want to sweep it around, like a speedometer on a car. I need to rotate it based upon a pivot point at the end of the image, rather than the image centre.

Can this be done?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can use a webview and put a canvas in it and play around with canvas. That's the easiest way.

Comment: I'd prefer not to go down the web view route. The main reason was to go native so I don't really want to host a web view - although it would mean I could use things such as Pixi.js or Easel.js which would make doing this much easier I admit. I have quite a complex 'scene' that is being hosted within a scrollview to allow panning. I have everything else cracked - I just have this outstanding issue of being able to rotate around a pivot point.